# automating deleting Yahoo emails

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE in Firefox to try to delete unread emails from Yahoo mail.  We have around 30,000 unread emails and, from what I see, Yahoo will only delete less than 100 each time you delete.

I recorded the steps.  When I play them back, the dropdown to select "unread" gets clicked.  However, the "unread" doesn't get displayed to click on it.

Also, is there a way to "read" what is displayed on the screen?  Sometimes Yahoo asks to confirm the deletion, sometimes it doesn't.  Is there a way to conditionally click it if it is there?

The odd thing is that the deleting worked for a while today and then reverted to the "unread" not getting displayed.  I find that hard to understand.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using only the recording feature?

Comment: I am not just using the recording feature.  Ultimately, I'd like to create a loop and loop through all the unread emails and delete them.  That is what I had working just yesterday.  However, the problem I detailed came up.  I thought maybe there was a deletion restriction so I tried today.  I looked like it was working.  Then it had the same problem again.

Comment: Now, if I look at the unread it says there are none.  Another place it tells me there are 19.000 unread.  It looks like yahoo mail issue more than anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's June 2021 and I have a solution:

Took me 10 min to recover 5 years old knowledge. Done via Selenium IDE, easy to install in FFox. then run script/project which I attached.
It's set now to run first delete with Prompt confirmation and then 40 times in the loop without. This is how it works in my security setup and I'm  in US, CA.
I imagine that for diff areas or security you might need that confirmation each time on `css=.M_1MYwXA:nth-child(3) .D_F`  **Are you Sure** button

I overall don't like this Se, dealt with it around 5 years ago, now they change interface and editing capababilites, if any Se guru here he/she can easely make it run smoother I think.

Prerequsites:

Before login into your yahoo in FFox and make it remember your password so script will login automatically, there is no any private data in it or stored passwords. This script will delete mail from default Folder = Inbox, make sure that upon login you're there.
Store code below as ddd.side  (extension for IDE)
Then you can watch 3min demo how to install IDE, open and run project.
All steps setup to run with  to handle delays, but still it's not a bulletproof, in my case I had to restart FF couple of times. Sometime it just doesn't open base url on first step.

I kept it running for couple of hours and it's DONE. 54000 emails of my wife gone.
I don't think I can attachd this file, so trying to paste,
LEt me know. This script works fine as of June 30 2021, yahoo  guys don't sleep so it might be different overtime.

### [image]

```
   {
  "id": "adc727d1-40c6-439d-8702-8f97739c8f44",
  "version": "2.0",
  "name": "X",
  "url": "https://mail.yahoo.com/",
  "tests": [{
    "id": "ffe439e1-39aa-4114-95f9-14b5cee731dd",
    "name": "X",
    "commands": [{
      "id": "5f61ee21-9745-485e-b113-d1515783dc68",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "open",
      "target": "/",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "5d019986-41d9-451a-a328-2681a6d3f439",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "times",
      "target": "40",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "89048b9d-1e3c-4e56-b8c7-17a9fe431233",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "css=.G_e > .D_F .D_F",
      "targets": [
        ["css=.G_e > .D_F .D_F", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='mail-app-component']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/span/button/span", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//span/button/span", "xpath:position"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "2a5a4320-d12e-43ef-8f13-ea340c3062a3",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "pause",
      "target": "3000",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "af49e7c3-6db0-4236-aa1f-93d94f2acf5c",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "css=.M_1MYwXA:nth-child(3) .D_F",
      "targets": [
        ["css=.M_1MYwXA:nth-child(3) .D_F", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='mail-app-component']/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/button/span", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//div[3]/button/span", "xpath:position"],
        ["xpath=//span[contains(.,'Delete')]", "xpath:innerText"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "5c463aa8-4782-473e-876c-73921aa75612",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "pause",
      "target": "1000",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "b089bb86-60f4-43ee-8031-e5ac930f2f71",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "css=.G_e > .D_F .D_F",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "3731ebc1-a0c9-46ac-8d7d-c56a2cf3b72a",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "css=.M_1MYwXA:nth-child(3) .D_F",
      "targets": [
        ["css=.M_6LEV", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=(//button[@type='button'])[192]", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//div[@id='modal-outer']/div/div/div/div[4]/button", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//div[7]/div/div/div/div/div[4]/button", "xpath:position"],
        ["xpath=//button[contains(.,'OK')]", "xpath:innerText"]
      ],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "cbb516e3-5c38-4ebe-b6ff-65f0fde58cb6",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "click",
      "target": "css=.M_6LEV",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }, {
      "id": "a5a50691-fe3f-4e2f-8788-cad5f9ef18fc",
      "comment": "",
      "command": "end",
      "target": "",
      "targets": [],
      "value": ""
    }]
  }],
  "suites": [{
    "id": "2f69f4d6-3aad-4a60-a137-15541cf6384a",
    "name": "Default Suite",
    "persistSession": false,
    "parallel": false,
    "timeout": 300,
    "tests": ["ffe439e1-39aa-4114-95f9-14b5cee731dd"]
  }],
  "urls": ["https://mail.yahoo.com/"],
  "plugins": []
}
```